# How to upload image with parameter multipart in swift

Tags: ios, swift, multipartform-data

[image]I attached the screen shot of request and response. How to pass this type of parameter, i am not able add this type parameter in request. Please make a structure/sample so i can use in my code. Any clarification/suggestion please let me know. thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried something? There are plenty of questions about Multipartform-data, you didn't find something useful? Seems like JSON inside "body"?

Comment: "Please make a structure/sample so i can use in my code"  Try finding somebody as a private tutor at craigslist or freelance.com.

Comment: @Larme - I tried but i am getting format issue for body because it is json inside "body", can you share link/sample code. it will helpful to me. Thanks

Comment: @Larme i got reference from ur code and i make as multiform-data, with JSON inside "Body". Now issue is if i am passing the image or image path from app then i am getting the response, but if i am accessing the image from the gallery, taking the image path and converting into data and passing then i am getting the error. Any suggestion please tell me. Thanks

Comment: Why use the imagePath? Pass the image you got. It's hard to tell what's wrong, because I don't know what you coded.

Comment: @Larme i posted the part of code that i am using for image from source and image from app.  Please find below.

Comment: If it doesn't work, edit your question with that code, don't post it as answer as it doesn't fix your issue.

Comment: @Larme Finally resolved the issue, issue with the size of image, reduce the size of image and upload then i am getting the success response. Thank you for your support . shortly I will post the working code

Answer (score -1):

```
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first! as String
    let imageName = "imageClicked.png" // name of the image to be saved.
    //let localPath = documentDirectory.appending(imageName)
  //  imageName which you have stored in the db at retrieval time
    let imagePath = String("\(documentDirectory)/\(imageName)")
    let fileName = (UIImage(named: imagePath)?.pngData())!
```

// Here i am selecting the image from source and getting the image path and converting into data. then getting the error.

// if i am taking image from app and converting into data getting the response.

```
    // Passing the image from App
    let fileName = (UIImage(named: "swift_file.png")?.pngData())!
```